# How to enable controller parameter validation for standalone MockMvc

Tags: testng, spring-test, mockmvc, spring-test-mvc

Controller

```
@RestController
@Validated
class MyController {

    @GetMapping("/foo")
    public String unwrapped(@Min(1) @RequestParam("param") int param) {
        return Integer.toString(param);
    }

    @GetMapping("/bar")
    public String wrapped(@ModelAttribute @Valid Wrapper bean) {
        return Integer.toString(bean.param);
    }

    static class Wrapper {

        @Min(1)
        int param;

        public void setParam(final int param) {
            this.param = param;
        }
    }
}
```

Test

```
public class MyControllerTest {

    MyController controller = new MyController();
    MockMvc mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
            .standaloneSetup(this.controller)
            .build();

    @Test // fails
    public void unwrapped() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/foo")
                .param("param", "0"))
                .andExpect(status().isBadRequest());
    }

    @Test // passes
    public void wrapped() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/bar")
                .param("param", "0"))
                .andExpect(status().isBadRequest());
    }
}
```

To enable (unwrapped) method parameter validation in spring the controller has to be annotated with `@Validated` and the `MethodValidationPostProcessor` must be added to the context.
Is it possible to add the `MethodValidationPostProcessor` bean to the standalone setup ?
The question might be reduced to how to add a `BeanPostProcessor` to a standalone MockMvc setup ?

Comment: it is working for \@validated controller with method consisting dto arguments with validation annotations upon its attributes. but not for validation annotations against controller method arguments directly. for latter case you need integation test (\@RunWith(SpringRunner.class and \@SpringMvcTest). and don't forget that \@validated upon class produces 500 http error on ConstraintValidationException and for required Bad Request response you have to implement exception handler per exception class.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is it possible to add the `MethodValidationPostProcessor` bean to the standalone setup ?

No, that is unfortunately not possible when using `MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup()` since that creates a `StubWebApplicationContext` behind the scenes which does **not** support `BeanPostProcessor`s.

Once [SPR-6380](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-6380) has been addressed (currently in the Spring Framework 5.x backlog), you will no longer need to rely on the `MethodValidationPostProcessor`. However, in the interim you will need to switch to the use of `MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup()` in order to be able to test the behavior added to you controller via `MethodValidationPostProcessor`.

### Original Erroneous Suggestion

<s>I don't think it's possible to do that directly; however, you could create a custom subclass of `StandaloneMockMvcBuilder` that overrides the `initWebAppContext()` method, delegates to `super.initWebAppContext()` to create the `WebApplicationContext`, and then registers the `MethodValidationPostProcessor` bean programmatically via `org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.StubWebApplicationContext.addBean(String, Object)`.</s>

Comment: OK. Out of curiosity, have you verified that your `unwrapped()` method is properly validated when you deploy your app?

Comment: I ask because validation is not officially supported for a `@RequestParam`. See the following JIRA issue for details: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-6380

Comment: Never mind: I just noticed this comment in that issue: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-6380?focusedCommentId=135728&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-135728

Comment: it does, a `ConstraintViolationException` is thrown

Comment: I apologize: my original suggestion could never work since `StubWebApplicationContext` explicitly does not support `BeanPostProcessor`s. However, I'll edit my answer to include an authoritative response.