# Testing @Validated RestController in standalone MockMvc not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-web, spring-validator

I have RestController annotated with @Validated for validating path variables / request parmas:

```
@RestController
@Validated
public class MainController implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent> {

    @Autowired
    private CarsService carsService;

    @ExceptionHandler
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    public void handleException(ConstraintViolationException ex) {}

    @GetMapping(
            value = "/",
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<?> getCars(
            @RequestParam(value = "offset", defaultValue = "0") @PositiveOrZero
                    Integer offset,
            @RequestParam(value = "limit", defaultValue = paginationLimitDefault)
            @Positive @Max(paginationLimitMax)
                    Integer limit) {
        ...
        ...
        Map responseBody = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        responseBody.put("offset", offset);
        responseBody.put("limit", limit);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(responseBody);
    }
}
```

Now, I want to unit test the controller level with standalone mockMvc:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class TestMainController {

    @InjectMocks
    private MainController mainController;

    @Mock
    private CarsService carsServiceMock;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void initMocks() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(mainController).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void getCarsInvalidOffset() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/")
                .param("offset", "-1"))
                .andExpect(status().isBadRequest());
    }

    @Test
    public void getCarsInvalidLimit() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/")
                .param("limit", "0"))
                .andExpect(status().isBadRequest());
        mockMvc.perform(get("/")
                .param("limit", "-1"))
                .andExpect(status().isBadRequest());
        mockMvc.perform(get("/")
                .param("limit", "101"))
                .andExpect(status().isBadRequest());
    }
}
```

The problem is that the tests with the invalid params (both tests in the code snippet above) where should have return bad request, actually returning 200 OK and as a result the test fails.
How can I fix it?
Thanks.

Comment: Does your validation works outside the test environment?

Comment: yes it does work.

Comment: Why start a Spring Boot Test for this? From memory you can either use `WebMvcTest` and autowire the `MockMvc` in and it will work if you need to setup the standalone setup to have the validator.

Comment: I've tried with `WebMvcTest` as well, didn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24049480/spring-mockmvc-doesnt-consider-validation-in-my-test

Comment: Most definitely a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49160611/how-to-enable-controller-parameter-validation-for-standalone-mockmvc. Workaound: use `MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup()` or `@WebMvcTest`.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I suspect that because you are mocking the MainController, the @Validated isn't taking effect. Try this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class TestMainController {

    @Autowired
    private MainController mainController;

    @MockBean
    private CarsService carsServiceMock;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void initMocks() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(context)
        .build();
    }
```

Comment: This is not a standaloneSetup.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible with standaloneSetup.

For more details refer: [How to enable controller parameter validation for standalone MockMvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49160611/how-to-enable-controller-parameter-validation-for-standalone-mockmvc)

For @Validated test case we need:

```
MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup()
```